# Finding specific range to copy based on a key word

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I have the following VBA code in excel

```
On Error Resume Next

Dim wk As Worksheet
Set wk = Sheets("ABC")
With Sheets("DEF")
   .Range("A6", .Columns("A").Find("", , xlValues, xlWhole).Offset(-1)).EntireRow.Copy _
    wk.Range("A" & wk.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
End With
```

The purpose of this code is to start from cell `A6` in sheet `DEF` (`A6` contains the word "Date") and copy the sheet range under A6 until the first blank row and then paste into sheet ABC.

Can you please help me improve this code to instead find the word "Date" which sits in cell A6 currently and do this same task? (ie lets say next time "Date" sits in cell A1)

Thanks.

Comment: Find "Date" instead of ""?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rDate As Range
    Dim rLast As Range
    Dim sFind As String

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wb.Sheets("DEF")
    Set wsDest = wb.Sheets("ABC")
    sFind = "Date"

    With wsSource
        Set rDate = .Cells.Find(sFind, .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
        If rDate Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No cell containing text """ & sFind & """ found in sheet '" & .Name & "'"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set rLast = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If rLast.Row <= rDate.Row Then
            MsgBox "No data found after """ & sFind & """ in sheet '" & .Name & "'"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    wsSource.Range(rDate.Offset(1), rLast).EntireRow.Copy wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your variables("Date" and last row).

```
Dim lRow As Long
Dim fWord As Range

Dim wk As Worksheet
Set wk = Sheets("ABC")

    With Sheets("DEF")
        lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set fWord = Columns("A").Find(what:="Date", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

        If Not fWord Is Nothing Then Rows(fWord.Row & ":" & lRow).Copy _
        wk.Range("A" & wk.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    End With
```